# issue while converting word doc to .ConvertToPDF using #syncfusion

Tags: c#, syncfusion

Recently I read about the new dll of ConvertToPDF which should simply convert Word document with its data to pdf.

The main problem is that when I load my existing Word and the rest according to the guidance at https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/converting-word-docs-to-pdfs.aspx then I try to replace some data (by reading Data Row from DataBase) using the `FINDANDREPLACE` method. I was expected after drawing my data and writing

```
 DocToPDFConverter converter = new DocToPDFConverter();
 doc = converter.ConvertToPDF(document);
 converter.Dispose();
 document.Close();
 doc.Save(" ManagerAward1 .pdf");
```

my Word file with all data save in the pdf document. But it's not and the PDf is empty. I am not sure which part of this information I am missing. below I will attach my code

Would you mind to help me ?

```
public void Render(DataSet Ds, PdfDocument doc)

        {

            foreach (DataRow DR in Ds.Tables[0].Rows)

            {

                WordDocument document = new WordDocument(SaveTempSample(".docx", Properties.Resources.ManagerAward), FormatType.Docx);

//This method will find and replace my data//

                DrawRTF(document, DR, doc);

//after replacing I need to convert that word to pdf by using these codes :

                DocToPDFConverter converter = new DocToPDFConverter();

                doc = converter.ConvertToPDF(document);

                converter.Dispose();

                document.Close();

                doc.Save(" ManagerAward1 .pdf");

                doc.Close();

            }

        }



private void DrawRTF(WordDocument document,DataRow DR, PdfDocument doc)

        {

            document.Replace("-1-", DR["GenderDesc"].ToString(), true, true);



            document.Replace("-2-", DR["NameF"].ToString(), false, true);

            document.Replace("-3-", String.Format("{0} {1}", DR["SectionName"].ToString().Trim(), DR["SchoolName"].ToString().Trim()), false, true);

            document.Replace("-6-", DR["Descript"].ToString(), false, true);

            document.Replace ("-8-", DR["TestName"].ToString(), false, true);

            document.Replace("-9-", DR["Datef"].ToString().Trim(), false, true);



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save pdf document before disposing the converter